# Ensuring profile pics have a face (PHP web app)

Tags: php

I have developed an in-house corporate web app that allows users to upload their own profile picture. However, some users are uploading pictures of their pets! Is there a way to ensure profile pictures have a face in them prior to it uploading?

I tried the PHP Face Detection Library but find it's not that effective. Looking for something more reliable and robust.

Comment: You'll need some AI...probably subscribing to a 3rd party cloud service is your best bet.